# Combine two rows in data frame in python

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a data frame which has two columns and one column has a duplicate values .I want to combine the rows into one . But I dont want to run any aggregation function . My data frame is

My data frame df

```
       CP                 CL

0    45538         [757, 1]

1    5548          [712515, 1]

2    7908          [251, 3]

3    7908          [7885, 1]
```

The result I want is as below

```
       CP                 CL

0    45538         [757, 1]

1    5548          [712515, 1]

2    7908          [[251, 3],[7885, 1]]
```

I tried with below code but aggregation doesn't work

```
agg_functions = {'CL': 'list'}
df_new = df.groupby(df['CP']).aggregate(agg_functions)
```

The above code doesn't work and gives error ,I am not sure how I can combine it using data frame functions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Remove the quotes around your `list` agg func since `list` is not a builtin agg func in pandas so pandas doesn't know how to aggregate

Change,

```
agg_functions = {'CL': 'list'}
```

to,

```
agg_functions = {'CL': list}
```